# Constant boolean value in Querydsl

Tags: java, querydsl

## Preamble

For some rudimentary filtering of records, based on permissions, I'm creating a number of implementations of the same interface, each of which can provide filtering/constraints for building a query. The response of each implementation is `AND`-combined (`anyOf`) with some other condition, before all of these are `OR`-combined (`allOf`).

One of these implementations may return something like this: `QComment.comment.author.eq(user)`. However, some of these implementations just want to express that the access is completely denied ("`false`") or allowed ("`true`").

This question is not about my business logic, that's why I glossed over it, but the point is that:

## Question

**I want to return a `BooleanExpression` that evaluates to `false`, resp. `true`**.

I've come up with the following:

```
BooleanExpression FALSE_CLAUSE = Expressions.FALSE.ne(Expressions.FALSE);
BooleanExpression TRUE_CLAUSE = Expressions.TRUE.eq(Expressions.TRUE);
```

While this works quite well, it seems rather ugly. Is there a better way in Querydsl to do this? I was expecting `BooleanExpression.FALSE` and `BooleanExpression.TRUE`. Surprised not to find those.

Answer (score 3):

I was equally surprised not to find this. 
The only improvement is

```
BooleanExpression FALSE_CLAUSE = Expressions.FALSE.isTrue();
BooleanExpression TRUE_CLAUSE = Expressions.TRUE.isTrue();
```

(which is the implementation of the methods above)